# How to add routes multiple times in routing table?

Tags: linux, networking, routing

Need to add same route multiple times in the routing table, or is there a way to maintain references in the routing table entries ? (may be with different priorities etc.)

Am working on a switch which adds default routes for their subnet if particular feature is enabled & there can be overlapping subnets. 
So In order to avoid maintaining refcnts at switch level , I was wondering if routing can do that for me ?

Let me know if this is feasible or not, Appreciate the help.

Comment: So you want to have multiple entries in your routing table that are the **exact same**? As in you want a routing table that has the default router listed more than once even though they are the same destination.

Comment: yes, thats what I am looking for